# Getting error when trying to format with cleave.js

Tags: javascript, html, cleave

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [cleave.js] Please check the element
at new Cleave (cleave.js:82:16)
at main.js:2:14
```

My js code:

```
var cleave = new Cleave('.pinenter',{
blocks: [3],
numericOnly: true });
```

This is my html :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pin" autocomplete="off" class="pinenter"><br>
```

Comment: As per your code and input, there is no error. Can you provide more details in your question?, I also tried same JS+HTML in a playground and there is no error.
See: https://jsfiddle.net/yde2q1b5/

Comment: Hmm im not sure what is going on then because the same thing works on my other pages but for some reason one page on my site keeps telling me to check my element.